# Xcode layout changed after clicking yes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter

[image]

All the tabs have been removed after clicking yes to something which I don't know. Now I cant edit provisioning and so on. What to do to get it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to tap the icon that's straight left of "Info" (highlighted in blue), left of the app name (slightly above and left of "Deployment Target").